# Which Google URL is currently used for sending notification using GCM

Tags: notifications, sms, google-cloud-messaging

What is the correct URL for dispatching Push Notifications using GCM:

A) "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"

B) "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send"

c) either A) or B)

It seems that B) is the correct (newer?) URL per Google specs but a lot of folks on these here Internets use A) in their examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the google documents on setting this up. [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

their example uses B and thats what i use and it works fine.

Have your tried A, if it works i expect they are URL's to the same thing

Comment: thanks. yes, they get ping responses noting the same IP and both work as expected. I appreciate the feedback.